Python C Extension When to Free Internal Free List?
Some Python objects - for example, instances of int, float and dict - use a free list to speed up allocations. The C API provides methods to clear such free lists.
By hardcoding PyXXX_ClearFreeList into gcmodule.c:clear_freelists, a module can clear the free list after gc, preventing memory leaks.
From the CPython source code:
    /* Clear free list only during the collection of the highest
     * generation */
    if (generation == NUM_GENERATIONS-1) {
        clear_freelists();
    }

static void
clear_freelists(void)
{
    (void)PyMethod_ClearFreeList();
    (void)PyFrame_ClearFreeList();
    (void)PyCFunction_ClearFreeList();
    (void)PyTuple_ClearFreeList();
#ifdef Py_USING_UNICODE
    (void)PyUnicode_ClearFreeList();
#endif
    (void)PyInt_ClearFreeList();
    (void)PyFloat_ClearFreeList();
}

However, if an extension module also uses a free list, does it need to clear that list after a (full) garbage collection? If so, how? Does the garbage collector provide a hook?
